Performance comparison between collecting struct, collecting array and collecting string
I have to make a data quality function that marks a row if a set of columns don't have a one to one mapping column with another set of columns in the same table.
For example, consider the following table
> CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t1
AS VALUES (1,2,4,5), (1,2,3,7), (1,2,NULL,5) AS (c1,c2,c3,c4);

> SELECT *
FROM t1

Output
c1  c2  c3   c4
1   2   4    5
1   2   3    7
1   2  Null  5

Now suppose the one to one mapping is in between (c1,c2) and (c3,c4). So I want to present something like -
'One to one error (c1,c2) has multiple mappings to (c3,c4) -> (NULL,5), (4,5), (3,7)'
I do need the NULL string or at least something to represent the null value.
I have made it with three different ways, with the difference being in the arguments of collect_set. Here are the three versions
All three have used the following CTE expression
WITH cte
AS (
  SELECT c1, c2, COALESCE(c3, 'NULL') AS c3, COALESCE(c4, 'NULL') AS c4
  FROM t1
)

First, using string in the collect_set
SELECT CONCAT('One to one error (c1,c2) has multiple mappings to (c3,c4) -> ', 
   ARRAY_JOIN(COLLECT_SET(CONCAT('(', c3,',', c4,')')),', '))
FROM cte
GROUP BY c1, c2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c3, c4) > 1

Second, using struct in the collect_set
SELECT CONCAT('One to one error (c1,c2) has multiple mappings to (c3,c4) -> ', 
   ARRAY_JOIN(TRANSFORM(COLLECT_SET(STRUCT(c3,c4)), st -> CONCAT('(', st.c3, ',', st.c4, ')')),', '))
FROM cte
GROUP BY c1, c2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c3, c4) > 1

Third is using array in the collect_set
SELECT CONCAT('One to one error (c1,c2) has multiple mappings to (c3,c4) -> ', 
   ARRAY_JOIN(TRANSFORM(COLLECT_SET(ARRAY(c3,c4)), ar -> CONCAT('(', ar[0], ',', ar[1], ')')),', '))
FROM cte
GROUP BY c1, c2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c3, c4) > 1

Is there any difference in performance of these three? I think that struct would be better than using string in the collect_set as it has a structure and might help in comparing things faster.
Also, if possible, can it be done in a better way?
The number of columns is not fixed in both sides and I will generate this query dynamically.
